# Rails for Java Desktop MVC

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, django, model-view-controller, desktop

I'm looking for a desktop application framework similar to Rails/Django but for Java desktop GUI's:

- Good ORM (xml, db, whatever)
- MVC
- Default directory structure
- View Helpers / CRUD support
- Open Source & Mature

Basically, I want to define a large number of models for a desktop application either in Java or schemas and have a simplistic GUI framework generated to begin extending.

Does anything out there do this or come close?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try looking at Griffon: http://griffon.codehaus.org/.  It's an MVC framework using the Groovy scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Monkeybars](http://monkeybars.rubyforge.org)? It's a nice JRuby MVC framework (somewhat inspired by Rails, I think) that runs on top of Swing; you can use any ORM you like with it. I've had a lot of luck with it.

I was using Swinger for testing, but according to http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/capybara-ate-swinger/ , I think Capybara will now drive Swing apps.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't quite spot on, have you looked at grails (http://grails.org)?

Comment: its not even close to spot on, the dude asked for a desktop environment

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/). If you prefer Ruby, then you might try [JRuby](http://jruby.org/).

Today, Web applications run smoothly just like desktop apps using ajax. Ext js is a good example.